# ASP.NET MVC 6 API and Jquery ajax problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I made an easy service to sort a list of integers for a class using ASP MVC 6.

My ajax post request to the API on a different local host is not working correctly.  The HTML/Javascript is here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="arr" />
        <button class="btn btn-lg" id="arrbtn">Push Me</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#arrbtn").click(function () {
                var thing = $("#arr").val().split(' ').map(Number);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://localhost:58453/api/sort",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ arr: thing }),//have also tried this without stringify, encoding as string, hardcoding a json with and without stringify
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert("plx");
                }).error(function () { alert("error");});
            });
            
            
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this on localhost, fiddler shows me that there is no header for "Content-type application/json", and the body of the request is blank.

If I remove the contentType and dataType fields from the request, data is sent, but the header now has

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

My API promptly passes null into my action and returns a bad request.

I know my API is working correctly as I can make a fiddler post and get a proper response back.

Edit 1:  Action Method on request.  Here is the whole controller
Edit 2:  Changed the string to array of numbers.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SortController : Controller
{

    [FromServices]
    public ISortRepository sortArray { get; set; }

    // POST api/sort
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit([FromBody]SortItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return HttpBadRequest();
        }
        //sortArray.stringToInts(item);
        sortArray.sort(item);
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your action method look like?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: Did you mean, different port on same localhost ?

Comment: Yes.  I have 2 instances of Visual Studio 2015 each running a localhost